# Why a finally block can't modify a returned Integer type data from catch block. Java

Tags: java, try-catch

So two facts I am aware:

1.Due to auto-boxing even    `Integer i = 9; i` it is still considered an object type, not primitive type.

2.In a `try-catch-finally` block, the `finally` can modify the value being returned by a `catch` block only `catch` block returns an object, not primitive data.

So why following code still prints out:

```
10
```

When `finally` suppose to modify the `returnVal` to `20` because `returnVal` is NOT a primitive data type?

```
public class test1 {

     Integer getInt() {
        Integer returnVal = 10;
        try {
            //some code here that will cause an exception
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return returnVal;
        }
        finally {
            returnVal += 10;
        }
        return returnVal;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        test1 tes = new test1();
        System.out.println(tes.getInt());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Note: If you want to throw an exception, just do it explicitly!  `throw new Exception();`

Comment: @BoristheSpider "At the time of the `finally` the reference being returned is already set in stone" actually we can change reference of object which will be returned in finally. We just need to set it again by using `return returnVal + 10;`.

Comment: @Pshemo true - sorry for spreading disinformation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following:

```
        returnVal += 10;
```

does not modify the object referenced by `returnVal` (that object is immutable). Instead, it creates a new object and changes `returnVal` to point to it. That has no effect on the original reference supplied to `return` - that original object is what's being returned.

Contrast this with

```
class Test2 {

    public static class MutableInteger {
        public Integer value;
        public MutableInteger(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    MutableInteger getInt() {
        MutableInteger returnVal = new MutableInteger(10);
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return returnVal;
        }
        finally {
            returnVal.value += 10;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Test2 test = new Test2();
        System.out.println(test.getInt().value);
    }
}
```

Here, `returnVal` is mutable, and the `finally` block modifies the object instead of rebinding the reference. As a result, the code prints out 20.

Answer (score 0):

The catch block completes the execution via return statement i.e. `return returnVal`, Since `returnVal` is of type Integer which is immutable object , modifying it in the finally block doesn't reflect the changes made to it. Had Integer been `mutable object` then you would see the value return as `20`. E.g.

```
class MyInteger {
    int value;

    public MyInteger(int i) {
        value = i;
    }

    public void add(int someVal) {
        value += someVal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyInteger{" +
                "value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
public class test1 {

     MyInteger getInt(){
         MyInteger returnVal = new MyInteger(10);

        try{
            String[] students = {"Harry","Paul"};
        System.out.println(students[3]);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return returnVal;
        }finally {
            returnVal.add(10);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test1 tes = new test1();
        System.out.println(tes.getInt());
    } 
}
```

Output 20 because MyInteger is mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any problem. Finally changes an  integer value just like expected

/**
 *
 * @author alikatkar
 */
public class FinallyTest {

```
public static int testInt() {
    int result = 0;

    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = 2;
        System.out.println("result in catch:"+result);
        return result = 2;
    } finally {
        return result = 3;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Returns:"+FinallyTest.testInt());
}
```

}

Output:
 result in catch:2

Returns:3

Comment: add 'return result;' after the 'finally' block.

Comment: You can NOT add return after finally block. Because the statement will be unreachable code

Comment: remove "throw new Exception()" in the try block and add some code to make sure a exception is caught then try again. My original code was modified by mods so it was a little confusing. Just try this and see if it still prints the same result.

Comment: I remove the throw exception and add int i=1/0; Output is the same. I tried only you had requested. This problem about blocks. So there will be no change with any changes inside the blocks. Finally block always run and method ends with return statement. Probably you have another problem, somehow you think cause of finally but I think it did not